# JavaScript variable scope/hoisting issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, getter-setter, hoisting

I'm having some very confusing issues with getting a variable from a different file after it is set locally in the file of origin. I know it has something to do with hoisting but after a while spent researching with no luck I thought it would be worth asking here.

I am trying to get the set `element` from my file `sequencer.js` like so:

```
var nxloader = require('../../helpers/nxloader');                                     

// Load matrix
var matrix = nxloader.load('matrix').getElement(); 
console.log(matrix);
```

From the file `nxloader.js` which sets the variable like so:

```
var $ = require('jquery');                                                            

/**
 * Variable to hold the element that is loaded.                                       
 */
var element = 'test';                                                                  

/**
 * Constructor                                                                        
 *
 * @returns {nxloader} instance of itself                                             
 */
var nxloader = function () {
    return this;
};

/**
 * Loads the element passed in
 *
 * @param {string} element  The element type to load
 */
nxloader.load = function (element) {

     // Switch on the element type
     switch (element) {
         // Is matrix
         case 'matrix':

            // load matrix
            nx.onload = loadMatrix;

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    // Implement fluent interface
    return this;
};

/**
 * Load the matrix element
 */
var loadMatrix = function () {

    // Colours
    nx.colorize("accent", "#ffbb4c");
    nx.colorize("fill", "#1D2632");

    // Specified size
    matrix1.col = 16;
    matrix1.row = 1;
    matrix1.init();
    matrix1.resize($(".step-sequencer-container").width(), $(".step-sequencer-container").height());

    // Set the element
    setElement(matrix1);

    // Implement fluent interface
    return this;
}

/**
 * Get the element
 * @return {nxelement} element
 */
nxloader.getElement = function () {
     return element;
}

/**
 * Local setter
 */
function setElement (elementToSet) {
     element = elementToSet;
};

module.exports = nxloader;
```

As some might guess, when the `console.log(matrix);` in the `sequencer.js` file returns `'test'` rather the element I'm hoping for. I know it has something to do with hoisting in JavaScript but I am confused how to solve it. I wanted a local setter so that it can't be set from other files. I wish the element to be set to the global `element` variable once the element has been loaded so that the other file can retrieve this `element` and use it as it wishes.

I'm using the [NexusUI](http://nexusosc.com/) library that has UI elements that are specific to web-audio programming.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I think it is a very simple and annoying problem!

**EDIT:** Put the actual code in the method `loadMatrix` for clarity.
**EDIT-2:** Included link to NexusUI library

Comment: That variable `element` is a global variable. Is that really what you intend?

Comment: The problem is not `element`, but `setElement(matrix1)` with in your `loadMatrix` - I see no point in your module, where you actually defined `matrix1`.

Comment: @Pointy I think it is but only because I want to be able to access it in the `getter` to return to other modules, is there another way that you can suggest that you would be better? I'm very open to ideas

Comment: Hi @Christoph, I've edited the post and put the actual code that is the `loadMatrix` function for clarity. As I understand, the `nx.onload` has the `matrix1` variable and from that I'm able to set the properties. What I want to then do is make the `matrix1` variable available to the other module. I know that it sets the properties as desired.

Comment: Well what's `nx`? You set `nx.onload` to that `loadMatrix` function but the function is never called.

Comment: @Pointy, `nx` is the variable from the `nexusUI.js` file that i've included in the header of the file. Sorry I didn't make this clear, it is a UI library that is specifically used for audio programming, details can be found [here](http://nexusosc.com/). I know that the `onload` function works as it formats the `matrix1` as desired, I can see it working on my web-page.

Comment: The issue isn't hoisting. It's simply a timing issue. I bet if you put that console.log inside a `setTimeout`, it will be defined. The issue is that `onload` is called after you `console.log`. You can check the value of `element` simply by typing it in your javascript console. I bet its set properly. Just not when you log it.

Comment: @CharlieMartin I'm afraid that isn't working either, using this line `setTimeout(console.log(nxloader.getElement()), 3000000);` it still returns `'test'`

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function as the first param. You are passing it undefined currently. This is causing your console.log to execute immediately and not after the delay. Wrap the console.log in a function.

Comment: @CharlieMartin You are quite correct, sorry for the silly mistake and thanks for pointing it out. It has worked. Any advice on how to make this synchronous so I can ensure that the variable is assigned?

Comment: the library you are using is the one that calls `onload`, so you can't really control when it gets called. what you can do is put your code inside of the `loadMatrix` function, where you know the value is set. That will become the entry point to your application logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is being set properly, but the `onload` function is being called **after** your `console.log` runs. So, the value has not been set at the time of logging. You can prove this by putting the log in a `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout(function { 
    console.log(matrix); 
}, 0);
```

This pushes the log to the end of the call stack and **after** the `onchange` function is called by the library meaning your matrix is ready.

Depending on how you want to structure your application, you can use a callback or a [Promise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn802826(v=vs.94).aspx) to deal with asynchronous issues like this. Or you can simply move your console.log to the `loadMatrix` function where you know you can safely access the element.